# Loop invariants quicksort

Tags: java, quicksort

How can I understand from the invariant that l is the correct value to be returned and how 
the initialisation of **l=low**; and **h=high**; establish the invariant?

```
/* invariant
         * low <= l <= h <= high
         * In region for indexes i with low <= i < end:
         *   elements are as originally, but rearranged.
         *   if i < l then arr[i] < x
         *   if i >= h then arr[i] >= x
         * Elements outside region are unchanged.
         */ 

private static int partition(int[] arr, int low, int high, int x)
{
        int l = low;
        int h = high;
         while (l<h)
         {
            if (arr[l] < x)    
               l =l +1;
            else
            {                           
                int x = arr[l];
                arr[l] = arr[h-1];
                arr[h-1] = x
                h = h-1;
             } 
         }
         return l;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are partition your array in two parts to start with. You pick the middle element `x` and then you are moving all elements smaller to `x` in left side this way all remaining right elements become bigger than `x`.

Once done, `x` is at its right position. Now you call the same method for left and right segments separately.

This way high and low represents the `lower` and `upper` index of the segments. e.g. if your arrays size is `10` and `x` ended up at position `4`(index=3) then for first sub list, low=0, high= 2.

Similarly for second sub list, low=4 and high=9.

Comment: I understand what the method does,my question is only regarding with the loop invariant that  How can i understand from the invariant that l is the correct value to be returned and how the initialisation of l=low; and h=high; establish the invariant?

Comment: @user1795732 what is the expression of your invariant?

Comment: @user1795732 You start from `l=low;` and `h=high;` and keep swapping the eligible elements and accordingly update `l` as `l =l +1;` and `h` as `h = h-1;`. This make `l` to go up and `h` to come down. Now notice your loop condition `while (l<h)`. You are looping until `l` is lower than `h`. Thus your `l` and `h` are behaving as invariant. Hope I am clear now.